# VS Code workspace storing additional script data

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I wanna build external editor for scripts stored in crm.
I have API which exposes script engine returning list of scripts containing ,script id, script name, content...

Editor will be Visual Studio Code plus my extension. Manage to build extension and get data, store scripts on in the folder and give them name from the response. Problem is in update, to send data back to the server i need to use id not the name.
Question: is there any kind of container in workspace where i can store all data related to every script such as Id?
Something like settings for every script containing scriptName:id, date, owner...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe https://code.visualstudio.com/api/extension-capabilities/common-capabilities#data-storage can help? You can store data either locally, in the workspace, or globally, in the user' storage space. Can be simple key/value pairs, or your own format.